# What are subspecies and Varients in Monster Hunter?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

So, I’m looking at a list for what monsters will be released for the highly anticipated Monster Hunter Generation Ultimant on the switch; (there are 95 large monsters if your wondering) and there’s a lot of conversation about which ones are subspecies, and which ones are variants of monsters. Can someone explain what the difference is between the two concerning the following points?

-do both variants and subspecies enable you to craft new equipment from them or will the equipment look like the original monster?

-do the variants and/or the subspecies receive different move sets?

-do the variants and/or the subspecies looks different from their original?

Here is the list for anyone who wants to see what i’m Talking about and if they wish to give me an example.

https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunter/comments/8ig37v/spoilers_monster_hunter_generations_ultimate/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sources for Generations Ultimate, but all your questions actually apply to Generations, and all of them can be answered.  I own MHG, and have played 3U and 4U, so I know about the subspecies and deviants.

> do both variants and subspecies enable you to craft new equipment from them or will the equipment look like the original monster?

Both subspecies and deviants give very different armor stats.  There are actually different versions of the **same** armor (Rathalos R vs Rathalos S) already present in the base game.  These versions let you mix armor skills more effectively

> do the variants and/or the subspecies receive different move sets?

Oh yeah.  Dreadqueen poison is very bad.

> do the variants and/or the subspecies looks different from their original?

They look very different.